# Changing url for NSMutableURLRequest after its being initialized

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

I am trying to see if there is a way to change the request url once the NSMutableURLRequest is being initialize? I looked into the instance method, but nowhere it indicates that you can change the url. I tried to make a request of "URL" and change it accordingly, but it still points to the old url.

Anyone know how to change this would like to know it.

Thanks.

Comment: -(void)setURL:(NSURL *)theURL

Comment: Generally NSMutableURLRequest is used for sending POST request where it is necessary to modify the HTTPMethod and body after the URL is being set. I am curious to know why you specifically need NSURLMutableURLRequest to do the job.

Comment: Mehfuz, you have a valid point there, however, what I have invoked in my method is basically either use of "Get" or "Post", and if its post then what needs to get into the body, and hence not part of the "URL" string anymore. Basically the calls that's being made is being invoked in the url, and there are some conditions where some contents for security reason should be invoked in "Body", so apache server doesn't caches it. However, I am trying to understand what difference it makes if the content is either in "Body", or "Header". Does it really makes a big difference? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method on NSMutableURLRequest called `- (void)setURL:(NSURL *)theURL`

Here's an example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSURL *anotherURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];
[req setURL:anotherURL];
```

Specifically, the method documentation is at:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableURLRequest/setURL: